# Redirect to another model's index action, and hence view index.erb - Rhomobile

Tags: ruby, rhomobile, rhodes

I am developing a Rhomobile application,on submit of a POST method, i am going to my 'Model 1' action, after execution of my action i want to redirect to another model's (Model 2) Index action and list the data.

I am from a Rails background, there i would have used URL, any similar concept exists here or any solution.

i tried, but it didn't worked for me render :controller => :model2, :action => :index

Answer (score 0):

**Please Note: I have never used `rhodes` and all of this information was acquired by simply reading the API documentation and taking a look at the source code.**

According to the [documentation](http://docs.rhomobile.com/en/5.4/guide/controlling_webview_behavior#controlling-navigation) You should be able to deal with this in a very railsy fashion eg

```
   def some_action 
     redirect controller: :model2, action: :index
   end
```

Seems the only caveat is if this redirection is to happen in a callback function. In this case the redirection should be handled by the `WebView` instead e.g.

```
  Rho::WebView.navigate(url_for(controller: :model2 action: :index))
```

Source for [Rho::RhoController#redirect](https://github.com/rhomobile/rhodes/blob/master/lib/framework/rho/rhocontroller.rb#L131) supports these statements in the documentation.

Additionally as you might notice above it appears that `Rho` has ported a lot of the rails like helpers including `url_for`

Comment: Yes, thanks for your help, actually i was doing a syntax error, as new to the technology, although found the same solution and appreciate your response.